# LVS: All connections are InActConn

Tags: load-balancing

All connections are InActConn

I'm a newbie using LVS. I've tried LVS/TUN and LVS/DR, the result is the same, all connections are InActConn. But the realservers can be reach (through PING). Pls help!!!

```
OS: CentOS 6.2
RemoteAddress:Port               Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn

UDP  192.168.10.240:2345 rr

-> 192.168.10.251:2345           Tunnel    1      0          10

-> 192.168.10.252:2345           Tunnel    1      0          9

-> 192.168.10.253:2345           Tunnel    1      0          9
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior for services not maintaining connections, like UDP. You may want to read the LVS Howto, especially the part about Active/Inactive connections :

http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.ipvsadm.html#ActiveConn

Answer (score 0):

Old Question : But I got to this post from Google and want to paste my findings here.

In the above answer, the link pasted by @remi-ggacogne missed 1 step for Real server.

You have to turn rp_filter off (esp. in Centos / RHEL ) https://www.slashroot.in/linux-kernel-rpfilter-settings-reverse-path-filtering

Open /etc/sysctl.conf and paste below lines ( as per your network interface )

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0

net.ipv4.conf.tunl0.rp_filter = 0
```

To make the above active -->

```
$systcl -p
```